# Android TV cast - Senders count limit

Tags: android, google-cast, google-tv, google-cast-sdk

What is the right way to set limit on senders count to only 1 user at a time. Should it be sender or receiver that disconnects previous session? or is there any right way to do it?

Tried sending message from receiver to old and new connected users indicating old one to disconnect and new one to operate normally, but old phones metadata is still visible in new phone.